# µPickle Couldn't derive type error on write

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

I'm trying to use µPickle in Scala.js to produce Json for Ajax request.
Here is my code:

```
    import upickle._
    import upickle.default._
    case class FmData(name: String, comment: String)
    val data = write(FmData("name", "comment"))
```

And I get error:

> Couldn't derive type FmData

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue happened to me before. It was happening when I was defining this case class in `package` object, other `object` or inside of *method*. However when I extracted it to a separate file, it was all fine and working.

Hope it helps.